# No member fields showing from zoovisitor in order fields setting

Tags: expresso-store

When viewing Order Fields under settings the select boxes are empty. Fresh install of EE 2.9 latest Expresso Store and Zoo Visitor. Should I not be able to map the ZooVisitor member fields or was that removed from 2.4.0 Store?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I used **updater** to install Expresso store. For what ever reason the Extension piece was not installed. I went into add-ons and manually installed all the peices for Store and it works now :). The zoo fields are showing now in Expresso Store to map.

Or it might have been Zoo Visitor just make sure all pieces for both are installed.